# A particular permutation on $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, permutation-groups

Let us consider  $\mathbb{Z}_N=\{0,1,\cdots N-1\}$.

Does there exist any permutation $\sigma$ on $\mathbb{Z}_N$ satisfying :

$$\exists p,q\in\mathbb{N}, ~~p,q\neq0 (mod~N) ~~\forall i,j\in \mathbb{Z}_N$$  the following formula holds $$q\sigma(i)(1+2\sigma(j))\equiv_{N} qi(1+2j)+2p$$

Comment: Well, there is $q=p=0.$ There is an $i$ with $\sigma(i)=0$ Then for this $i$ and all $j$ one has $qi(1+2j)+2p=0$

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  It needs a minor amendment.

Comment: Take even $N$, $p=N/2$, $q=1$ and the identity permutation as $\sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

We must have $4p \equiv_N 0$ meaning $N=2p$ or $N=4p$ (since $p=0$ is forbidden):  Let $i_0$ have $\sigma(i_0)=0.$ Then you require that for all $j,$ $$0 \equiv_N qi_0(1+2j)+2p$$
If $i_0=0$ then $0 \equiv_N 2p.$ There are still the other values of $i$ to consider but @MaxAlekseyev has given a solution.

Otherwise, putting $j=0$ and $1$, we have that $qi_0+2p\equiv 3qi_0+2p \equiv 0$ Hence $2qi_0 \equiv 0$ and also $4p \equiv 0.$

So another solution (after checking) is $N=4p=2q$ and $\sigma$ the identity permutation. In fact, $\sigma$ can be any permutation which preserves parity.